# Wordpress Pagination Not Working After Transfer from Localhost

Tags: permalinks, pagination, paginate-links

I have the following code for wordpress pagination:

```
function sds_pagination(){
global $wp_query;
$big = 99999999999999;
echo paginate_links(array(
    'base'=> str_replace($big,'%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
    'format' =>'?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
));
}
```

This works perfectly on localhost but when I transfer the theme to my client's site, pagination doesn't work. instead of giving me a url such as site_url/category_name/page/2, it gives out site_url/page/276447231/ . Category is excluded despite the fact that I have mirrored the permalink settings with the one in localhost. What could be the problem?

Update:
I have found out that the client uses a plugin called WP no category base and another called disable canonical url redirects. could these plugins have an effect on the pagination code?

Comment: Rewrites are still a bit foreign to me, but any plugin that rewrites URL's can have an impact on this. I would suggest to disable these plugins, flush the permalinks once or twice and then test everything. If this resolves the issue, find out which plugin are causing the issue and then contact that respective plugin author

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thanks Pieter. I think you are right. I will test with the plugins to see.

Comment: @nelson I see this question is 4 years old, but I was wondering, do you remember what was the issue? I'm recently facing the same problem.

Comment: @delux Hello. Yeah, it's been quite long but I remember disabling the plugins and also flushing the permalinks on the live site for it to work. 

I have been off wordpress for quite a while but try that. Alternatively try writing custom permalinks. Check my profile to see one of the examples I was given by Rachel Cherry (Bama Designer). But disabling any plugin that rewrites URL and flushing should work

Comment: @nelson thanks! Changing the permalinks to have query params, instead of "/param/val" fixed the issue for me.